# What is v8::Value::ToDetailString() function for?

Tags: v8

I can't find any description for this function.
Even after v8 sources analyze it is still unclear for me, because
it is ended by "`RETURN_NATIVE_CALL(to_detail_string...`", and I can't find `to_detail_string` in my sources.

Here is supposed to be a documentation about this function:
https://v8docs.nodesource.com/io.js-3.0/dc/d0a/classv8_1_1_value.html#a2f9770296dc2c8d274bc8cc0dca243e5

Copy/paste from v8 sources:

```
V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<String> ToDetailString(
      Local<Context> context) const;

MaybeLocal<String> Value::ToDetailString(Local<Context> context) const {
  auto obj = Utils::OpenHandle(this);
  if (obj->IsString()) return ToApiHandle<String>(obj);
  PREPARE_FOR_EXECUTION(context, "ToDetailString", String);
  Local<String> result;
  has_pending_exception =
      !ToLocal<String>(i::Execution::ToDetailString(isolate, obj), &result);
  RETURN_ON_FAILED_EXECUTION(String);
  RETURN_ESCAPED(result);
}

MaybeHandle<Object> Execution::ToDetailString(
    Isolate* isolate, Handle<Object> obj) {
  RETURN_NATIVE_CALL(to_detail_string, { obj });
}
```

Could someone provide any hints or links to documentation?

I could just call it and see results, but I hope answers will contain some useful information and links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is implemented in messages.js by ToDetailString.

Answer (score 0):

The function definition from v8/src/messages.js:

```
function ToDetailString(obj) {
  if (obj != null && IS_OBJECT(obj) && obj.toString === ObjectToString) {
    var constructor = obj.constructor;
    if (typeof constructor == "function") {
      var constructorName = constructor.name;
      if (IS_STRING(constructorName) && constructorName !== "") {
        return "#<" + constructorName + ">";
      }
    }
  }
  return ToStringCheckErrorObject(obj);
}
```

See also a fragment of a discussion from here:
http://logs.nodejs.org/v8/2013-02-05

`ToDetailString prints #<constructor name> if the object to be printed
doesn't have a custom toString method.
ToString prints [object <class of object>].
ToDetailString also handles error objects differently.`